# In an UML 2.5 State Machine, how can I model sending a Signal as an effect on a transition in a convenient way?

Tags: uml, communication, specifications, finite-state-machine

In an UML 2.5 State Machine, how can I model sending a Signal as an effect on a transition in a *convenient* way?

In one of the older UML versions you simply prefixed the name of the signal with a `send` keyword in the effect part of the transition specification, like:

```
response [buffer.size>N] / send request
```

But in UML 2.5 the effect *must* be a Behavior, either an Activity, Function, Interaction, ProtocolStatemachine, StateMachine or Opaque (just uninterpreted text). Which makes authoring a communication protocol state machine very cumbersome. Let alone using it to *design* in it.

I think I have collected virtually *all* available books about this subject and if there is a convenient way to do it, it uses a descendent of Telelogic's Tau (Either IBM Rational Rose UML/SDL family or Rhapsody, I'm not sure) which is essentially derived from the ITU SDL 2000 specification method. But I'ld like to stay close to UML 2.5 as possible.

Further more I know that the ITU has mandated the development of a UML profile to facilitate the transition from SDL to UML, but this aspect wasn't clearly addressed.

Aside:  In the terminology of UML 2.5 there is an important, albeit, implicit distinction between a "protocol" and a "communication protocol".  UML explicitly states that a "protocol" is the way the operations of a class are (supposed) to be used. Which leaves a "communications protocol" implicitly to be the prescription on how to communication between entities. (end of aside)

Anyone?

Comment: I just skimmed the UML 2.5 spec for _communication protocol_ but could not find any trace. Can you elaborate on what you're refering with your _Aside_?

Comment: @qwerty_so To clarify, with regard to the notion of _communication protocol_ in the sense I described above, you are completely right; there is no definition of it in UML and UML 2.5. specifically.   
I only hoped that people wouldn't confuse the UML notion of "protocol" with my definition of  "communication protocol".  Because I encountered that confusion already in the literature and online.

Comment: @qwerty_so Wikipedia as a useful definition of both: UML 2.5 obviously refers to the  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Protocol_(object-oriented_programming) and the other is https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Communication_protocol respectively.

Comment: @qwerty_so w.r.t to the distinction between an Signal and Event, I understand the confusion Take a look at the standard (https://www.omg.org/spec/UML/2.5.1/PDF) §13.3.2 Figure 13.2 Events, shows that a Signal derives from Event via 2 subclasses. So, a Signal _is an_ Event.  The important property of a signal is that it represents an asynchronous and non-blocking data carrying Event from one object to another (§10.3.1.1. Signals). The other way around, an Event is an abstraction of a Signal.

Comment: @qwerty_so A Trigger is in essence nothing more than the specification of a placeholder in an object (fancy term used in the standard is Classifier) linking an Event to some effect entailed by the occurrence of that Event (i.e. triggering that effect to happen). (§13.4.11.1)

Comment: You opened a can of worms here. Why did they introduce a specific Protocol Statemachine (it's basically a statemachine attached to something you use for communication; so why is there no MoneyTransferStatemachine or ...)? Also, why after more than 20 years is there no metamodel of UML I can load into a tool which _describes_ UML? The current one has just the element with no or little notes for elements.

Comment: I meanwhile understand what they mean with _Signal_ and _Event_ (the latter is the physical thing you can watch while the first is the _ethernal_ 'thing' traveleing to a detached recipient ignoring any _reality_). Alas, I don't have an answer. Just questions ;-)

Comment: I get an unexplained downvote on every UML question I post. Someone has issues?

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way than to model a behavior as the effect of a transition. However this behavior can be an opaque behavior, where you can use any textual syntax. So, you could write "send request" and this string can be displayed as you describe. Of course "request" is then just text and not a reference to a signal. If your tool supports Alf (action language for foundational UML), you could use this language and the text would actually be referencing the signal.

The specification allows another compact way to show the sending of a signal. You can use the symbol for the send signal action in a state machine diagram. This notation maps to an effect activity that just contains this send signal action. I'm not aware of any tools that support this, though.

Answer (score 0):

If I see it right, a `Signal` is sent by a `Trigger` which is part of an AD. The `Trigger` has that `Signal` as one of its properties. And they are just created there. So I guess that you can not create a `Signal` from within a state transition. It's only the other way around that you react on Signals in a SM.

I'm not that expert in SMs but you're probably after having another concurrent SM make a transition when that specific one happens. I guess that's somehow possible (I could imagine using a guard here), but I can't really answer that part. Maybe it 'triggers' someone else :-)

Comment: Not quite correct: A 'Trigger' is part of a transition specification, specifying at which occurrence of a specified `Signal` or `Event` the transition will happen.  And a `Signal` has no `Trigger` as a property. But you could say that a `Trigger` can have a specific association (reference) to a `Signal`; i.e. the `Signal` on which the transition will trigger!

Comment: to keep this post on the subject, my question wasn't about modeling triggering transitions with `Signal`; that's easy.

But how do I model _sending_ a `Signal` as the **effect** of a transition, without going through al kinds of complicated modelling. Since previous versions of UML allowed to do that. (See OP)

Comment: Yes, I know that you want to send a signal and I explainted that this is not possible.

Comment: Cross check UML/implementation in Enterprise Architect. You are right and it's wrongly swapped above. Will fix.

Comment: EA is nice example of an UML tools in which using signals in a state machine or message sequence diagram is quite cumbersome. It is fine for structural modelling and low-level behavioural modelling.

But I dropped it in favour of MagicDraw, which support UML 2.5 (EA 15 still only supports 2.1) and has better support for signals. Although it isn't ideal either; I reported a load of issues regard divergences with respect to the standard and incongruous design choices.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably true. As said, I'm no expert in SMs. I use them sometimes but in my area it's not that important. Looking at the number of answers here it seems that SMs are not used too often all around. Regarding design: EA just sucks :-/ But that opens a can of worms.